# PHP code returns only one word of a database record

Tags: php, database, string, mysqli

I ran into a complete halt and I can't figure out what the problem is. My written PHP code returns only one word of a DB record, even though the syntax in the code is correct. I'm out of ideas, so I ask your help!

Here's the starting code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         $pavadinimas = $row['pavadinimas'];

         if ($row['busena']=='Užimtas'){
             $uzimta = 'checked';
             $laisva =' ';
         }
         else {
            $uzimta = ' ';
            $laisva = 'checked';
         }
```

**And the place where it should return full string, but returns only one word:**

```
<input class='form-control' type='text' name='pavadinimas' value=" . $pavadinimas . "><Br/>
```

Thanks for the help!

****** UPDATE *****

FULL CODE:

```
    <?php
include 'incl.php';
echo "<h4>Prie duomenų bazės prisijungta sėkmingai. Galite naudotis sistema.    </h4>
<hr/>";

$sql = "SELECT id, pavadinimas, vietos, busena, nuo, iki FROM kambariai";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         $pavadinimas = $row['pavadinimas'];

         echo var_dump($pavadinimas);

         if ($row['busena']=='Užimtas'){
             $uzimta = 'checked';
             $laisva =' ';
         }
         else {
            $uzimta = ' ';
            $laisva = 'checked';
         }
        echo "
        <form class='valdymas' action='update.php' method='POST'>
        <input style='display:none; visible:none; opacity:0;' type='text' name='id' value=" . $row["id"] . ">
        Kambario eiliškumas plane:<br/><b style='color:red;font-size:15pt;'><center>
        " . $row['id'] . "</center></b><br/><Br/>
        Pavadinimas: 
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='pavadinimas' value=" . $pavadinimas . "><Br/>
        Vietų skaičius: 
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='vietos' value=" . $row["vietos"] . "><Br/>
        Būsena: <Br/>
        Užimtas <input class='radio-control' type='radio' name='busena' value='Užimtas' 
        "; echo "" . $uzimta . "";
        echo "><Br/>
        Laisvas <input class='radio-control' type='radio' name='busena' value='Laisvas'
        "; echo "" . $laisva . "";
        echo "><Br/><Br/>";
        if ($row["busena"] == 'Užimtas'){
        echo "Jei užimtas, nuo: 
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='nuo' value=" . $row["nuo"] . ">
        Jei užimtas, iki: 
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='iki' value=" . $row["iki"] . ">";
        }else {
        echo "Jei užimtas, nuo:
        <input class='form-control'type='text' name='nuo'>
        Jei užimtas, iki: 
        <input class='form-control' type='text' name='iki'>";
        }
        echo "<input class='btn btn-default btn-success' type='submit' value='Atnaujinti informaciją'></div><hr/>
        </form>";

    }
} else {
    echo "Nėra duomenų.";
}
```

?>

Comment: You're going to need to give us more information... what's the value of `var_dump($pavadinimas)`? What's your SQL actually returning?  Have you confirmed there's not just 1 row being returned?  Also, if you're trying to output a list check out PHP's `implode` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: `value='$pavadinimas'`

Comment: define "full string", because I don't see the rest of your while loop?

Comment: Well the var_dump is:

    string 'Kambarys Nr. 1' (length=14) 

and it's the string I should get, but I get only 'Kambarys'.
The strange thing is that the other rows are returning correctly.

I'm including the full code int the original post (sorry, didn't have time to clean up):

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver, it worked. What a silly thing of me to not see that..

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, the value attribute values are not quoted. Add single quotes around each one.

Change:
    value=" . $pavadinimas . ">
To:
    value='" . $pavadinimas . "'>